# numbers of subsets for a set $A$ for which the equation $x+y=2n+1$ hasn't solutions.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find the numbers of subsets for the set: $\displaystyle A= \{1,2,\ldots,2n\}$ for which the equation $\displaystyle x+y=2n+1$ has not solutions.

I have no idea. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For problems like this, if you have no better idea, do it by hand for $n=1$ and $n=2$.  Often you get an idea how it works, then can generalize from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break the set $\{1,2,\dots,2n\}$ into the $n$ pairs $\{1,2n\},\{2,2n-1\},\dots,\{n,n+1\}$; any solution to $x+y=2n+1$ must have $\{x,y\}$ equal to one of these $n$ pairs. Thus, you’re looking for the subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,2n\}$ that contain at most one member of each pair. In how many ways can you do this? If you get stuck, mouse-over the spoiler protected bit below.

> To form such a subset you must make a $3$-way choice for each pair: take neither member, take the smaller member, or take the larger member. Thus, the total number of such subsets is $3^n$.

Comment: I have a question, where you wrote $\{1,n\},\{2,n-1\}$ it should be $\{1,2n\},\{2,2n-1\}$, no ?

Comment: @Iuli: It should indeed; thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  divide the numbers in $A$ into pairs that sum to $2n+1$.  How many pairs are there?  How many elements of each pair can be in your subset?